Why do I get a mismatch between box. space and tensor format in torch when I run the code about rayrllib?
When I try to use Ray RLlib for training, line 228 in the complex input network in raylib displays an error:
**SampleBatch.OBS: torch.reshape(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: reshape(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray. **
I understand that this is an input error belonging to ‘input_dict’(component in the function). I checked the format of input_dict and found that it is defined in gym .space ‘box’ object, not a tensor format that can be recognized by torch, so I want to know how to solve this problem
I tried to let the ‘box’ space sample by itself (box. sample()), but this did not meet the requirements in the follow-up obviously.
**component = [torch.tensor(box.sample(), dtype=torch.float32) for box in component]
component = torch.stack(component)
**
At the same time, I found that after the code ran for some time, the component format automatically changed to the tensor format that torch can recognize. I wan to figure out which part of the code is causing this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
